# Why Method App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController::guard does not exist and MemberExtra table not fill with data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

thanks for helping
I have some error when insert data i nto database, that is guard does not exit when I try to register by using this controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Models\MemberExtra;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index(){
        return view('users.register');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'referrer_id' => 'required',
            'position' => 'required', 
            'username' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {  
         $ref_id = $data['referrer_id'];
        $poss = $data['position'];
        $posid =  getLastChildOfLR($ref_id,$poss);
 
        return User::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'referrer_id' => $data['referrer_id'],
            'position' => $data['position'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'join_date' => Carbon::today(),
            'posid' => $posid       
        ]);
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        $this->guard()->login($user);
        MemberExtra::create([
           'user_id' => $user['id'],
           'left_paid' => 0,
           'right_paid' => 0,
           'left_free' => 0,
           'right_free' => 0,
           'left_bv' => 0,
           'right_bv' => 0,
        ]);
       updateMemberBelow($user['id'], 'FREE');  
       return $this->registered($request, $user) ?: redirect()->route('home');
      
    }
}
```

when register , show this error
[image]

and I refresh the page , user data is inserted into database but MemberExtra data still not insert

[image]

And this guard does not exist error happen again and again whenever register.
How can fix this error
Can someone help me

Comment: `$this->guard()` what is this supposed to point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller I didn't see the `RegistersUsers` trait which have `guard` function.

You have missed to write below in your controller. By default this function exist in `RegistersUsers` this trait

```
/**
 * Get the guard to be used during registration.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('your guard name'); 
}
```